A closed subspace of a Banach space is complemented iff there is a projection on it

Given a Banach space $(E, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ and a (linear) subspace $M\subseteq E$ , we say that $P : E \rightarrow M$ is a projection if it is linear, bounded, surjective and satisfies $P^2 = P$ (where $P^2 = P \circ P$). Also, we say that $M$ is complemented in $E$ if there is a closed subspace $L \subseteq E$ such that $E= L \oplus M$ 
Claim. A subspace $M\subseteq E$ is complemented in $E \iff$ There is a projection $P : E \rightarrow M$

I am trying to prove this in order to use it to another proof. My attempt consist on the following:
$\boxed{\Leftarrow}$ We can take $L:= \ker P$ .
First observe that if $m \in M \implies \exists v \in E: P(v) = m \implies P(m) = P^2(v) = P(v) = m \implies P|_M = Id_M$
Given $x \in E$, take $m:=P(x)$ . Then, by linearity and $P^2=P$:
$$P(x-m) = P(x) - P(m) = m - m = 0 \implies x-m \in L \implies x \in L + M \implies E = L + M$$
Also, if $v \in L \cap M \implies P(v) = 0 \land P(v) = v \implies v = 0 \implies L\cap M = \{0\}$ , so $E = L \oplus M$ .
$\boxed{\Rightarrow}$ Since $E= L \oplus M$ then $\forall x \in E \, \exists ! (l,m) \in L \times M : x = l + m$ . Take $P:E \rightarrow M$ the map that assings to each $x$ the unique $m \in M$  . This map is clearly linear and surjective. The problem is that I do not know how to prove that it is bounded. I have seen that in similar excercises it is suggested to use the Closed Graph Theorem, but I am not used to it and do not know how to do it, so any possible help would be appreciated.
EDIT
I had an idea that no needs to use the Close Graph Theorem. Let $\{ x_n \}_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \subset E $ such that $x_n \rightarrow 0$ . For all $n \in \Bbb{N}$ there exists unique $(l_n , m_n) \in L \times M$ such that $x_n = l_n + m_n$ . Taking limits we have:
$$0 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (l_n + m_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} l_n + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m_n \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m_n = - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} l_n$$
Since $L$ and $M$ are both closed: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m_n = - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} l_n \in L \cap M = \{0\} \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P x_n= 0 \implies P$ is continuous on $0$ and then it is continuous on all $E$ . Is this fine or I left something?

Sorry, I mean surjective. But being surjective does not implies that $ P = I $ , since $ P $ is defined from $E$ to $M$ and there is no a identitiy map between this sets.

Also: you have defined algebraically complemented subspaces. Any subspace $M$ is going to be algebraically complemented, by Zorn's lemma. The projection condition is equivalent to $M$ being topologically complemented, which requires the assumption that both $M$ and $L$ must be closed.

@TheoBendit This notation comes from my Functional analysis book and many other books of Linear algebra use it, it does not have anything wrong.

@TheoBendit You are right, I forgot to say that $L$ must be closed. I have updated it.

If I remember correctly, you need a Banach space for the closed graph theorem ?

@julio_es_sui_glace Yes, in fact I forgot to mention that E is Banach, thanks for noticing!
